# Theming contact page form

Tags: 8, hooks, emails, theming

How to add in Drupal 8 a custom (suggestion) default contact page template ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Way 1: Use drupal template suggestion:**

You can enable the template suggestions by following changes as mention in 
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates

Once you have the suggestions enabled you can see, drupal suggests few template possiblities for any page, you can use any of the suggested template.

https://cl.ly/1f2T0x1a1F2n

**Way2: Declare custom template suggestions**

Or you can customd define template based on any logic by implmenting `hook_theme_suggestions_page_alter()`.

**Example:**

https://sqndr.github.io/d8-theming-guide/theme-hooks-and-theme-hook-suggestions/theme-hook-suggestions.html

Comment: glad it helped you!